# How to disable Http Response Headers that arent set in the applicationHost.config or the web.config?

Tags: iis, iis-10, iisnode

Hi I have a windows server with IIS 10 on where I am hosting angularjs web apps with the help of IIS-Node. I've been trying to harden the response headers and I find that Im doubling up on some of them.

For instance:  x-frame-options: is listed twice the first time it is loaded it is SAME ORIGIN which is not set in either applicationHost.config or webhost.config but is being added from somewhere Im not aware of, the second  x-frame-options: is shown as DENY which is what I expect it to be as I did set this using applicationHost.config.
A similar thing is happening with cache-control in the browser (chrome) it is shown as public, max-age=0,No-store when I only set it as No-store using applicationHost.config. So again cache-control:public, max-age=0, is being set somewhere else, not by me.

Please can any one tell me how to turn off these unwanted response headers?
I have searched IIS and Googled but I keep getting pointed back toward applicationHost.config or web.config. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If they come from Node.js, you can only disable at that level.

Comment: Could you share the iis feature snapshot of HTTP response header? [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrFfl.png)  if you want to remove or change the value of the response header you could use iis URL rewrite rule. [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/varunm/2013/04/23/remove-unwanted-http-response-headers/)